# Non-blocking channel operations in go. Send?

Tags: go, channel

I'm going through [Go by Example: Non-Blocking Channel Operations](https://gobyexample.com/non-blocking-channel-operations)

As far as I understand, the first `select` is triggering the `default` case because there are nothing in the `messages` channel, and if the `default` case didn't exist, we would receive a `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!` error, right?

Well, I cannot figure out how can I trigger the second `select`, specifically trigger the  `case messages <- msg:`

As I thought, it should work opposite to the receive. So if there's a buffer for 2 messages and we send the 3rd message to the channel, it would trigger the `default` clause, but the `messages` channel is empty, so why in the second select does it trigger the `default` clause? And how can I trigger the `case messages <- msg:` clause?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> why in the second select does it trigger the default clause?

Because the channel is unbuffered and there is no other go routine blocked on receiving.

> how can I trigger the case messages <- msg: clause?

You can either:

1. Make `messages` buffered

   ```
   messages := make(chan string, 1)
   ```

   https://play.golang.org/p/b1aO6N-dYf
2. Create another go routine that is blocked on receiving

   ```
   go func() {
       fmt.Println("Received from other go routine", <-messages)
   }()
   ```

   https://play.golang.org/p/Z7e1ZcO3C5

Comment: even more questions :D  
but hopefully I'll figure out it on my own, thank you!

Comment: @Arno, read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660533/why-using-unbuffered-channel-in-the-the-same-goroutine-gives-a-deadlock for the explanations :)